# Is it possible to customize Json element's Datatype as per Json schema?

Tags: java, json, xml, stax, xml-to-json

Converting XML to JSON through StAXON parser, there are datatype mismatch between Json Schema (expected) and actual Response JSON

For ex: 
As per Swagger Schema, we are expecting a “**String**” value for a field but XML to JSON parser gives us “**Integer**” which is not matching with Swagger/Schema document.

In Swagger/Json Schema accountId type mentioned as String.

```
"accountId" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "description" : "The Id of the account",
            "readOnly" : true
          }
```

The XML element value of accountId is: `< accountId>123</ accountId>`
After converting XML to JSON the accountId is: `**123**` 
but as per schema our expectation is accountId: `**“123”**`

**Universal parsing logic of XML to JSON:**

1. If the element has only Numbers but starts with Zero: `<accountId>0123</accountId>` then Json output is: `String  { accountId : “0123” }`
2. If the element has only Numbers but not starts with Zero: `<accountId>123</accountId>` then Json output is: `Integer  { accountId : 123 }`
3. If the element has contains character: `<accountName>Abc</ accountName>` then Json output is: `String { accountName : “Abc”)`

It will convert Json as per the data, not with any schema, obviously I didn't feed any schema while parsing Staxon parser.

Is there any way I can change the JSON which should match with the expect Json schema.
As per the above scenario I am expecting a String value, it should look at the schema and make the datatype of a field.
Note: Don't want to convert all to String as well.

Thanks in advance!!!